# Multiple commands during an SSH inside an SSH session

Tags: bash, ssh, amazon-ec2, read

I have a local machine which is supposed to make an SSH session to a remote `master` machine and then another inner SSH session from the `master` to each of some remote `slaves`, and then execute 2 commands i.e. to delete a specific directory and recreate it.

Note that the local machine has passwordless SSH to the master and the master has passwordless SSH to the slaves. Also all hostnames are known in `.ssh/config` of the local/master machines and the hostnames of the slaves are in `slaves.txt` locally and I read them from there.

So what I do and works is this:

```
username="ubuntu"
masterHostname="myMaster"
while read line
do

    #Remove previous folders and create new ones.
    ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line "rm -rf Input Output Partition""
    ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line "mkdir -p EC2_WORKSPACE/$project Input Output Partition""


    #Update changed files...
    ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line "rsync --delete -avzh /EC2_NFS/$project/* EC2_WORKSPACE/$project""

done < slaves.txt
```

This cluster is on Amazon EC2 and I have noticed that there are 6 SSH sessions created at each iteration which induces a significant delay. I would like to combine these 3 commands into 1 to get fewer SSH connections. So I tried to combine the first 2 commands into

```
ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line "rm -rf Input Output Partition && mkdir -p EC2_WORKSPACE/$project Input Output Partition""
```

But it doesn't work as expected. It seems to execute the first one (`rm -rf Input Output Partition`) and then exits the session and goes on. What can I do?

Comment: Instead of such indirection in command you can use `-J` option that would define your jump host.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider that `&&` is a logical operator. It does *not* mean "also run this command" it means "run this command if the other succeeded".

That means if the `rm` command fails (which will happen if any of the three directories don't exist) then the `mkdir` won't be executed. This does not sound like the behaviour you want; if the directories don't exist, it's probably fine to create them.

**Use `;`**

The semicolon `;` is used to separate commands. The commands are run sequentially, waiting for each before continuing onto the next, but their success or failure has no impact on each other.

**Escape inner quotes**

Quotes inside other quotes should be escaped, otherwise you're creating an extra end point and start point. Your command:

```
ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line "rm -rf Input Output Partition && mkdir -p EC2_WORKSPACE/$project Input Output Partition""
```

Becomes:

```
ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line \"rm -rf Input Output Partition && mkdir -p EC2_WORKSPACE/$project Input OutputPartition\""
```

Your current command, because of the lack of escaped quotes should be executing:

```
ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line "rm -rf Input Output Partition
```

if that succeeds:

```
mkdir -p EC2_WORKSPACE/$project Input Output Partition"" # runs on your local machine
```

You'll notice the syntax highlighting shows the entire command as red on here, which means the whole command is the string being passed to ssh. Check your local machine; you may have the directories `Input` `Output` and `Partition` where you were running this.

Comment: I understand your points. One part I was confused by was the semicolon, since I thought it would execute more than 1 commands at the same time which is why I didn't use it.

Comment: The semicolon will not cause the commands to execute at the same time see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/x7243.html) as a reference for executing commands. The `&` causes commands to run int he background, which means they wont be waited to finish before moving onto the next.

Answer (score 11):

You can always define in your jumpbox [Multiplexing in OpenSSH](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing)

> Multiplexing is the ability to send more than one signal over a single
>   line or connection. With multiplexing, OpenSSH can re-use an existing
>   TCP connection for multiple concurrent SSH sessions rather than
>   creating a new one each time.
>
> An advantage with SSH multiplexing is that the overhead of creating
>   new TCP connections is eliminated. The overall number of connections
>   that a machine may accept is a finite resource and the limit is more
>   noticeable on some machines than on others, and varies greatly
>   depending on both load and usage. There is also significant delay when
>   opening a new connection. Activities that repeatedly open new
>   connections can be significantly sped up using multiplexing.

For that do in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
ControlPersist 30m
```

In this way, any consecutive connections made to the same server in the following 30 minutes will be done reusing the previous ssh connection.

You can also define it for a machine or group of machines. Taken from the link provided.

```
Host machine1
    HostName machine1.example.org
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/controlmasters/%r@%h:%p
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPersist 10m
```

Comment: That's interesting! Is there a way to explicitly turn it on and off for a given connection? Seems like overkill to so drastically change all SSH connections for this one use case. Can it be used in a more precise manner? To start multiplexing only a certain connection?

Comment: @Centimane yeah, updated the answer

Comment: I would suggest to put the socket in user's home rather than a world read-writable `/tmp/`.

Comment: @heemayl Good point. I will edit it when in a computer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Also looks like, according to `man ssh`, `ControlPath`, `ControlMaster` and `ControlPersist` are valid options to pass an `ssh` command using `-o`. Could be an even more precise use case, set up the multiplexing in the first `ssh` of the script and recycle it for the others, but otherwise avoid the performance penalty. I wonder what the benchmark of multiplexing VS not for 3 SSH connections, given that "There is also significant delay when opening a new connection"

Comment: @Centimane I am using it for my Jumpbox/Ansible box and the difference is fairly noticeable.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Noticeable good I assume? Are you performing lots of SSH connections? I'm wondering at which point multiplexing gets better performance than just normal connections. According to your quote, for a single connection it is worse to use multiplexing. But is it quicker if you only do 2 SSH connections? 3? At which point does the added startup time payoff in reduced connection times is what I'm wondering. Surely it's different per environment, but how would it look in an ideal scenario (such as between two VMs on the same box). I'm not asking you do this testing, just food for thought.

Comment: @Centimane When I need, I do *LOTS* of ssh connections to the same server. If you are doing single connections to the same server, you do not need this configuration.

Answer (score 4):

You can put all your commands into a separate script on your "master" server.

**Master Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf "Input Output Partition"
mkdir -p "EC2_WORKSPACE/$project Input Output Partition"
```

Then in your ssh script call it like this:
**SSH Script**

```
username="ubuntu"
masterHostname="myMaster"
while read line
do
ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line < /path/to/masterscript.sh"
ssh -n $username@$masterHostname "ssh -t -t $username@$line "rsync --delete -avzh /EC2_NFS/$project/* EC2_WORKSPACE/$project""
done < slaves.txt
```

**OR**
if all files must be on the initial machine you could do something like this:

**script1**

```
script2="/path/to/script2"
username="ubuntu"
while read line; do
cat $script2 | ssh -t -t $username@line
done < slaves.txt
```

**script2**

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf "Input Output Partition"
mkdir -p "EC2_WORKSPACE/$project Input Output Partition"
rsync --delete -avzh "/EC2_NFS/$project/* EC2_WORKSPACE/$project"
```

**ssh script**

```
script1="/path/to/script1"
username="ubuntu"
masterHostname="myMaster"
cat $script1 | ssh -n $username@$masterHostname
```

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago, I had occasion to use control sockets like the other answers recommend (this answer is essentially a combination of using control sockets like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381980/70524) and scripts like [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381975/70524)).

The use case was a hack: The `authorized_keys` of the target user was overwritten periodically by a scheduled task and I wanted to quickly test things without going through red-tape needed to add something to that file. So I'd setup a while loop which added the key to that file as needed, run my test, and the cancel the loop. However, there would be a small window where the scheduled task would overwrite the file and my loop would still be `sleep`ing. So, setting up a control socket at the start would let my script SSH later without problems:

```
#! /bin/bash -xe
. "${CONFIG_DIR}/scripts/setup-ssh.sh"

# Build and test
export TEST_LABEL="${_started_by}-${BUILD_TAG%-BUILD*}"
#...
xargs --arg-file test-list \
    --no-run-if-empty \
    --process-slot-var=NUM \
    --max-procs=${#SERVERS[@]} \
    --max-args="${BATCH_SIZE:-20}" \
    "${CONFIG_DIR}/scripts/run-test.sh"
```

Where `setup-ssh.sh` is:

```
export SSH_CONFIG="${CONFIG_DIR}/scripts/.ssh-config"
mapfile -t SERVERS < "${CONFIG_DIR}/scripts/hosts"

for SERVER in "${SERVERS[@]}"
do
    while ! ssh -F "${SSH_CONFIG}" "${SERVER}" -fnN; do sleep 1; done
    scp -F "${SSH_CONFIG}" "${CONFIG_DIR}/scripts/ssh-script.sh" "${SERVER}":"${TEST_LABEL}.sh"
done
```

And `.ssh-config`:

```
Host test-*
  User test
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath /tmp/ssh-%h-%p-%r
```

And `run-test.sh`:

```
mapfile -t TEST_SERVERS < "${CONFIG_DIR}/scripts/hosts"
ssh -F "${SSH_CONFIG}" "${TEST_SERVERS[$NUM]}" "./${TEST_LABEL}.sh"
```

The sequence goes like this:

- The main script (shown first) sources `setup-ssh.sh`.
- `setup-ssh.sh` busy-loops the servers until all of them have a control socket setup. The `hosts` file simply lists the server hostnames one per line.
- Since the configuration specifying the control socket is only in `${CONFIG_DIR}/scripts/.ssh-config`, unless I specify that file using `-F`, SSH connections won't use it. So this allows me to use the control socket only where I need them using the `F` option.
- The setup script also copies the test execution script to the servers. The execution script itself contains a bunch of commands, and because I copied the execution script, I don't have to worry about an additional layer of quoting for SSH (and the additional cognitive overhead for figuring out what gets expanded when).
- Then the main script uses `xargs` to distribute the workload over the servers, by starting new jobs as soon as running ones end.